# re-use of an xml in C#

Tags: c#, xml

i have created an xml file from my c# application i want to use the file after creation but it shows me an exception that the file is already in use?? i think i have to close the file or something.. here is the source code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create the XmlDocument. 
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml("<item><name>salman</name></item>"); //Your string here 

    // Save the document to a file and auto-indent the output. 
    XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(@"D:\data.xml", null);
    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    doc.Save(writer);
    ///////////////

    XmlDataDocument xmlDatadoc = new XmlDataDocument();
    xmlDatadoc.DataSet.ReadXml(@"D:\data.xml");// here is the exception!!!!!

    //now reading the created file and display it in grid view

    DataSet ds = new DataSet("Books DataSet");
    ds = xmlDatadoc.DataSet;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.DefaultViewManager;
    dataGridView1.DataMember = "CP";
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to dispose of your `XmlTextWriter` in order to close the file. This is best done with a `using` statement:

```
using(XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlWriter.Create(@"D:\data.xml"))
{ 
    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    doc.Save(writer);
}
```

You should use the same pattern with the reader (and in fact, any object that implements `IDisposable`).

Comment: "in fact, any object that implements IDisposable" what is that??

Comment: I have solved but got last problem: dataGridView1.DataMember = "CP"; 
not everytime the root = CP how can i make it as variable?

Comment: @salman - IDispoable is an interface. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx

Answer (score 8):

You need to close the Writer:

```
 doc.Save(writer);
 writer.Close();
```

Or even better, enclose it in a `using` block:

```
// Save the document to a file and auto-indent the output. 
using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(@"D:\data.xml", null))
{
   writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
   doc.Save(writer);
}
```

The using statement will assure an exception-safe Close.

And use the reader in the same way.

Comment: XmlTextWriter.Create is the preferred method of instantiating this object. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.create.aspx

Comment: +1, can also dispose it, e.g.  with `using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(...))`

Comment: Indeed, you should not only use `Create` to create the writer, you should use `XmlWriter`, not the deprecated `XmlTextWriter`.